# jquery+AJAX - Update MySQL record via Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am loading record details into a modal allowing the user to edit. What I am trying to achieve is to have the user update the record in the modal and then submit to the MySQL table via AJAX / jQuery, however, afte pressing the "Save Changes" button nothing happens. I checked the JS Query and can confirm that the button is linked correctly and also managed to update the database when directly addressing the PHP update script. Not sure why the script refuses to start

Modal:

```
    <div id="output"></div>

<!-- Modal MYMODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Record</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- ID No. -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>ID No.:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dataPID" name="dataPID" size="5" disabled />
        </div>
        <!-- /.id number -->                                        

        <!-- Category -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataCat" name="dataCat" />
        </div>
        <!-- /.category -->

        <!-- Issue -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Issue:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataIssue" name="dataIssue" />
        </div>
        <!-- /.issue -->

        <!-- Department Responsible -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Department Responsible:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataDeptResp" name="dataDeptResp" />
        </div>
        <!-- /.department responsible -->

        <!-- Experience -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Experience:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dataExp" name="dataExp" />
        </div>
        <!-- /.experience -->

        <!-- textarea -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Description:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="dataDesc" name="dataDesc" rows="3" ></textarea>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="SaveChanges" name="SaveChanges" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
        <button type="button" id="DeleteRecord" name="DeleteRecord" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Record</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.Modal MYMODAL -->
```

Javascript:

```
$("#SaveChanges").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php",
        data: { action:"update_mysqli",PID:$("#dataPID").val(), Category:$("#dataCat").val(), Issue:$("#dataIssue").val(), Department_Responsible:$("#dataDeptResp").val(), Experience:$("#dataExp").val(), Description:$("#dataDesc").val()}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"text",                                     

        success: function(data) {
            $('#output').html(data); 
            drawVisualization();   
        },
    });
});
```

ajax_action.php

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='update_mysqli')) {

    // include connection details
    include 'connect_db.php';

    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    //Output any connection error
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $db->connect_errno .') '. $db->connect_error);
    }

    // get variables and sanitize
    $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['PID']);
    $cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Category']);
    $issue = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Issue']);
    $dept_resp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Department_Responsible']);
    $exp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Experience']);
    $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Description']);

    // check if record exists based on ID number      
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM qci_problems_index_new WHERE PID='".$pid."'");

    // if record is found, update accordingly
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){ 

        $sql = "UPDATE qci_problems_index_new SET Category = '$cat', Issue = '$issue', Department_Responsible = '$dept_resp', Experience = '$exp', Description = '$desc' WHERE PID = '$pid'";

        if (!$db->query($sql)) {
        echo "Error - Update of record PID " . $pid . " failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
        }
    } else {
        // if no record with relevant PID is found, create new record
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `qci_problems_index_new`(`PID`, `Category`, `Issue`, `Department_Responsible`, `Experience`, `Description`) VALUES ('".$pid."', '".$cat."', '".$issue."', '".$dept_resp."', '".$exp."', '".$desc."')";

        if (!$db->query($sql)) {
        echo "Error - could not insert new record: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
        }

    }

    echo "Success, record updated successfully";

    //close connection
    $db->close();

}
```

EDIT 1:
Chrome Console says the following:
[image: XHR2]
[image: error]

EDIT 2:
updated code

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Checked the PHP-error log for errors? Checked the network tab to see if an actual call have been made and, in case it has, what the actual response is?

Comment: Btw.. You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` isn't as secure as one would think...

Comment: I did check and my logs are not showing anything. the request goes through and it works when directly addressing the PHP script.

Comment: You say that the request goes through, have you checked that the data is correctly passed as well? And the response?

Comment: I adjusted the PHP script to grab all variables from $_GET to check whether there was a problem with the update query, but no issue there. variables were passed over correctly and updated accordingly. the issue is somewhere between the Modal and JS I think, PHP didnt display any error message either.

Comment: So the database gets updated, but you don't get a response in the call? Please clearify what the issue actually is.

Comment: Just tested again and database updates fine with both mysqli + PDO, the call doesnt seem to get through.

Comment: Yes, the call get's through. It's the response you don't get. There's a big difference. Check the network tab in your browser when you're making the call to see the response from your PHP-script.

Comment: Chrome console says that the requests was sent out, but the response row remains empty. Guess that means no response from the php script, hence a mysqli error?

Answer (score 1):

Change you data type to json and content type to text,add your get variable to the post request

```
$("#SaveChanges").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php",
        data: { action:"update_mysqli",PID:$("#dataPID").val(), Category:$("#dataCat").val(), Issue:$("#dataIssue").val(), Department_Responsible:$("#dataDeptResp").val(), Experience:$("#dataExp").val(), Description:$("#dataDesc").val()}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"text",

        success: function(data) {
            $('#output').html(data); 
            drawVisualization();   
        },
    });
});
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='update_mysqli')) {
```

Comment: I suspected that before, but even with the above adjustments it doesnt work. I removed the disabled PID input field as I thought it might cause troubles with $_POST, but also no result.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. You can send a query string on a post request...

Comment: where can I check the status code for xhr? Sorry, not really good with JS and AJAX...

Comment: in the navigation panel of your browser console

Comment: "jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> "

Comment: followed by references to the google jquery min library

Comment: just got another 2: " drawVisualization is not defined" and "Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined"

Comment: i don't think these errors are related to your ajax request look at the xhr request in you network tab

Comment: xhr request is sent, but no response received as this is the only row thats greyed out and has a "TIME" remark where the milliseconds are supposed to be.

Comment: can you post a screenshot with the xhr request body, do you have error enabled on your php page?

Comment: please see the edit. PHP error reporting(E_ALL) doesnt pick up anything.

Comment: click on the xhr request and you should see there a tab to prview the xhr request body, i have updated my answer

Comment: that means you have php errors, try enabling php error to see the problem you are facing

Comment: I turned on E_ALL on all pages as well have added display_errors', 1); just in case, but not a single error pops up. What am I missing here? The same AJAX approach works fine with Fullcalendar for example when doing CRUD. what I really dont get is why it works when I run the php script directly via $_GET?

Comment: did you set the contentType and Data type properly,can you post a screen with the xhr headers?

Comment: xhr headers are recognizing the content as text and Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 . the request looks ok, just the response seems to be missing completely. See the new screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value "**update_mysql**" in "**action**" parameter in the ajax URL(plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php?**action=update_mysql**). On the other hand your condition in ajax_action.php will only be executed the code if the value of "action" parameter is "**update_mysqli**"

Change the following line

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action']=='update_mysqli'))
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action']=='update_mysql'))
```

in your ajax_action.php file.

OR

Alternatively, you can pass value **update_mysqli** instead of **update_mysql** for your **action** parameter in ajax call.
Since you are using mysqli, you will prefer this for the sake of best practice as you are using mysqli functions inside code.